Spring Boot JSESSIONID cookie is sent even when request is not authorized and returned 403
I'm using Spring Boot version 3.2.1 and have encountered an issue with JSESSIONID cookies.
When I make a request that requires authentication, I receive an invalid JSESSIONID cookie. However, a valid JSESSIONID cookie is issued after logging in through my endpoint, replacing the invalid one. Is this expected behaviour? Should I receive a JSESSIONID cookie even when the user is not authenticated?
# application.yaml

allowed-origin: "http://localhost"
allowed-credentials: true

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      persistent: true
      cookie:
        secure: true

// Security configuration

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration(
    private val properties: AuthProperties,
    private val customLogoutSuccessHandler: CustomLogoutSuccessHandler
) {

    @Bean
    fun bCryptPasswordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(http: HttpSecurity): AuthenticationManager {
        val builder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder::class.java)
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder())
        return builder.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): UserDetailsService {
        val users = properties.credentials.map {
            User.builder()
                .username(it.username)
                .password(bCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(it.password))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                .build()
        }

        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users)
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain =
        http
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .headers { headers -> headers.cacheControl { it.disable() } }
            .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED) }
            .authorizeHttpRequests {
                it.requestMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/logout").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .logout {
                it.logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
                it.logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
            }
            .build()
}

// Auth. controller

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
class AuthController(private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager) {

    @PostMapping("/login")
    fun login(@RequestBody loginRequest: LoginRequestDto, request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) {
        val authToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password).apply {
            details = WebAuthenticationDetails(request)
        }

        runCatching {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken).also {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = it
                request.session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
                response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
            }
        }.onFailure {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed: ${it.message}")
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/logout")
    fun logout(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) {
        request.session.invalidate()
        response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
    }

    // TODO - returning a new sessionid cookie when it's not auth and return 403
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun helloWorld(): String {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}

// CORS filter configuration
@Configuration
class CorsFilterConfiguration(
    @Value("\${allowed-origin}") val allowedOrigin: String,
    @Value("\${allowed-credentials}") val allowedCredentials: Boolean,
) {

    @Bean
    fun corsFilter(): CorsFilter {
        val config = CorsConfiguration().apply {
            allowedOrigins = listOf(allowedOrigin)
            allowedMethods = listOf("*")
            allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
            allowCredentials = allowedCredentials
            maxAge = 3600
        }
        return UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource().apply {
            registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
        }.run { CorsFilter(this@run) }
    }
}


Yes it is expected. Everytime you make a request and u don’t have a JSESSIONID - you get one. Doesn’t mean you are authenticated, just means you got a JSESSIONID
